# How to get Parent Div via Helper Meteorjs

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to get access to the parent div or any div via an helper i set up in meteorjs.

For instance how can i get the div with a class of "form-group" for the isRegion helper ?

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select  name="{{regionsPart.name}}" type="select" class="form-control fields regionsField">
          {{#each regions}}
            {{#if isRegion}}
            <option class="choiceRegion" value="{{region}}" selected>{{region}}</option>
            {{else}}
            <option class="choiceRegion" value="{{region}}">{{region}}</option>
            {{/if}}
          {{/each}}
        </select>
      </div>
```

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
   'isRegion' : function(){
     var parentData = Template.parentData(1)
     var regions = Session.get('regions')
     var region = this.region;
     console.log($(this) trying to get the parent div for further use )
  )}

Thank you very much.
```

Comment: are you trying access it via helpers?

Comment: Yes, i would like to be able to access the parent div of where the helper isRegion is called. I need it to modify other divs as there are multiple and similar locations where isRegion is called.

Comment: you are misusing the helper construct in Meteor here, helpers should provide the data for context.

Comment: you should not manipulate the dom via helpers, $(this), i guess will not even work though i have not tested same

Comment: You could try doing it via the [rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_rendered) function instead of a helper. It gives you access to the DOM in the template (although I have no idea if you can traverse to the outer DOM from there).